# Can't pass a variable to a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I am using the below example code and have a problem where I can't pass the Request.RawUrl value into an object that extends the Control object (class Test below).

When I use the line:

```
<Test1:Test runat="server" ID="testControl" Target="<%# Request.RawUrl %>"></Test1:Test>
```

I find that the Target property is never called.

If I use this line instead:

```
<Test1:Test runat="server" ID="testControl" Target="<%# Request.RawUrl %> test"></Test1:Test>
```

the string value `"<%# Request.RawUrl %> test"` is passed to the Target property.

If I use this line as explained in many posts online:

```
<Test1:Test runat="server" ID="testControl" Target="<%= Request.RawUrl %>"></Test1:Test>
```

the string value `"<%= Request.RawUrl %>"` is passed to the Target property.

I need to get the value of Request.RawUrl passed to the Target Property of my Test control object. Does anyone have any ideas where I am going wrong?

---

Control:

```
namespace Testing
{
    public class Test : Control
    {
        public Test()
        {

        }

        private string target;

        public string Target
        {
            get { return target; }
            set { target = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

User Control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Test1" Assembly="Test" Namespace="Testing" %>

<Test1:Test runat="server" ID="testControl" Target="<%# Request.RawUrl %>"></Test1:Test>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call testControl.DataBind() in code.  <%# gets set when DataBind() is called.  <%= is equivalent to Response.Write().